# Span in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this button and I want to make it calls methods when I click on "Select" and another method when I click "Change":

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" *ngIf="!edit" class="btn btn-default">
    <span *ngIf="isNullOrUndefined(class?.classForeignId)">Select</span>
    <span *ngIf="!isNullOrUndefined(class?.classForeignId)">Change</span>
</button>
```

i have tried to put `(click)="method()"`, but did not work. I'm so confused to what can I do. Please help

Comment: or separate events on spans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(click)="method()"` is indeed the way to go.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" *ngIf="!edit" class="btn btn-default">
  <span (click)="selectMethod()" *ngIf="isNullOrUndefined(class?.classForeignId)">Select </span>
  <span (click)="changeMethod()" *ngIf="!isNullOrUndefined(class?.classForeignId)">Change </span>
</button>
```

---

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcspw2)

Answer (score 2):

Create 2 different buttons instead of 2 different spans in button and call the different methods in `click` on both  elements.

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" *ngIf="!edit && isNullOrUndefined(class?.classForeignId)" class="btn btn-default" (click)="method1()">
      Select         
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" *ngIf="!edit && !isNullOrUndefined(class?.classForeignId)" class="btn btn-default" (click)="method2()"> 
      Change 
    </button>
```